# Add Azure appinsights to ASP.NET Framework aspx pages to log all SQL dependencies/sql command text

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure-application-insights

I am working on a legacy asp.net aspx web page application. ( .net framework v4.6.2).
We would like to set up azure appinsights logging to track our app logs.
The most important aspect ,we want to achieve is to view the sql dependencies ( ability to view sql context/code that is executed/ called ) in App Insights.
Goal : is to log the SQL command text that is being executed by server code .

I tried googling a lot of articles ,but most of them are on .net core only , and that is not helpful

[image]

I had tried to follow this article : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net

But I am still not able to view the sql Logs

I had tried to follow this article : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net

Added the Azure appinsights Nuget packages , Added Log4net to log trace info

Sometimes, I am not even seeing the normal logs like api calls etc.

Any help /guidance is much appreciated

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Could you please share your source code which you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Check the below workaround to track SQL queries and dependencies in Application Insights for `Asp.Net Framework` Application.

- I have followed the same [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net) which you have provided to add the Application Insights automatically.
- Add the Application Insights Connection String in `ApplicationInsights.config` file.
- As mentioned in the [MSDoc Dependency tracking in Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-dependencies#advanced-sql-tracking-to-get-full-sql-query), I have added the below setting in  `ApplicationInsights.config`, under `<TelemetryModules>`.

```cs
<EnableSqlCommandTextInstrumentation>true</EnableSqlCommandTextInstrumentation>
```

- Make sure your `Web.config` has the below settings added.

> ```cs
> <add name="TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule" type="Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation.TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule, Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation" />
> <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />   </httpModules>
> ```
>
> ```cs
> <modules>
>      <remove name="TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule" />
>      <add name="TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule" type="Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation.TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule, Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation" preCondition="managedHandler" />
>      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
>      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />  
> </modules>
> ```

- Add the `Connection string` in the configuration section in `Web.config` or add it in the controller itself.

```cs
<connectionStrings>
    <add name ="AppInsightsConn" connectionString="Data Source=******\\******;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=True"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

***My Code in Controller:***

I have taken code references from the MSDoc and [1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/custom-operations-tracking) and[2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/custom-operations-tracking)

```cs
        public TelemetryClient tc;
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            tc = new TelemetryClient();
          
            string myconn = "Data Source=******\\******;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=True";

            //var myconn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AppInsightsConn"].ConnectionString;
            var sqlConn = new SqlConnection(myconn);
            sqlConn.Open();

            string cmdtxt = "Select  * from MyDetails";
            var sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(cmdtxt, sqlConn);


            string dependencyType = "My SQL";
            string dependencyName = "Harshitha SQL Dependency";
            var time = DateTimeOffset.Now;

            using (var dep = tc.StartOperation<DependencyTelemetry>(dependencyName))
            {
                dep.Telemetry.Type = dependencyType;
                dep.Telemetry.Data = cmdtxt;
                dep.Telemetry.Success = true;

                var reader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

                dep.Telemetry.Duration = DateTimeOffset.Now - time;
            }

            sqlConn.Close();
            return View();
        }
```

***Traces in Application Insights:***

[image]

***Dependencies:***
[image]

Comment: During your test, did u ran the app on Local IIS or Express IIS.

Comment: I ran on Local IIS.