# Track Dapper's SQL commands' text to Application Insights

Tags: .net, azure, azure-application-insights, dapper

My applications use Dapper for database work (with SQL Server). They are ASP.NET Core web applications (self-hosted) running in Docker containers.

When these services were instrumented for Application Insights, the DB dependencies are captured automatically (I didn't have to do anything), but the Command property is always captured as "server-name | database-name", and not the actual SQL. What should I do to enable detailed trace, including the actual command text? Can this be just enabled for the SqlConnection or for Dapper, or do I need some external components? I keep seeing Status Monitor mentioned, but I'm a bit baffled by how one would apply it to my context.

Comment: What is the framework of your app?

Comment: Please share you .csproj file.

Answer (score 1):

It just so happened that I stumbled upon the answer myself, posting here in case somebody else is wondering about the same.

Dapper, of course, has nothing to do with this, it is the SqlClient that is instrumented. To add the SQL text to the traces, following configuration adjustment is enough (at least, was enough in my case):

```
services
  // - configure all services, including App.Insights telemetry, and then:
  .ConfigureTelemetryModule<DependencyTrackingTelemetryModule>((module, o) =>
  {
      module.EnableSqlCommandTextInstrumentation = true;
  });
```

It literally says so here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-dependencies#advanced-sql-tracking-to-get-full-sql-query

Comment: Yes..you can check the similar issue which I have answered in [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76323650/19648279)

Comment: With all respect, when you're setting the SQL text manually in the telemetry (referring to your link), it is quite different from what I was trying to do.

Comment: You have set EnableSqlCommandTextInstrumentation in code where as I have done it in config file.

Comment: I have set manually to show the test sql result.I mean the sol is same ..need to set EnableSqlCommandTextInstrumentation key.

Comment: So you have - indeed! Then you're right, yes - it is the same.